# Question already exists, but has an old, out of date accepted answer?

Tags: discussion

[My question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3661/how-to-back-order-domain) has been asked but the answer appears to be a bit outdated (and things happen fast with ICANN).
How can I encourage a newer answer (or at least get some current eyeballs on it.)
(B/c the only folks looking an **answered** question are the ones who don't **already** know the answer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put a bounty on an already answered question, even if it belongs to someone else: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/. That should help.